# Show that $m=6k+5$ has at least one prime divisor of the form $6n+5$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

What's the best way of approaching this kind of questions?

Comment: Did you mean to type $k$ twice? if $m=6k+5$ then $m$ has one prime divisor of the form $6k+5$ if and only if $m$ itself is prime....

Comment: @Rustyn: "of the form $6k+5$" means that the factor is $5$ mod $6$, not that it necessarily equals $m$

Comment: @robjohn I know what that means... but he should use a different letter...

Comment: @Rustyn, changed it to prevent confusion. Thanks

Comment: @Xorserq You're welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Imagine factoring $m$ into primes.
$m$ cannot have $2$ or $3$ as a factor (why?)
All other primes are equivalent to $1$ or $5 \pmod 6$
If you multiply together numbers equivalent to $1 \pmod 6 \dots$

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!